# How to save pgAdmin layout

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Each time I re-open pgAdmin I have to open the path to my database tables. Is there a way to have the path saved so it automatically re-opens to the desired layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with the latest version of pgAdmin4?

It saves the previous tree state and will open it once you connect to that respective server, Feature implemented: https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/1253